# How To read a column which has indentations in its name in dataflow ADF

Tags: dataset, azure-data-factory

[image]I am having trouble using the source column in the Derived Column stage of my Data Flow. The column names in my source file are as follows:

employee   employee   employee
name       mobile     joining
number     date

Is there any way to use these columns in the Data Flow? I am receiving an error when attempting to use them in the Derived Column stage. Please advise.

Comment: can you please share error you are facing?

Comment: If I am using any column with indentation from source then it says "Column not found"

Comment: Where is indentation? Is it space between words in column name?

Comment: yes, like in question you can see there is new line between every word of column name

Comment: Try to give the column name within the braces `{employee name}`

Comment: Your question is not displaying the indentation, so it is hard to diagnose. In the raw text, do you know if it is represented as a \t (tab) character?

Comment: Yes, i tried with these curly braces but it is not recognising the column. And it has\n between the column names

Comment: What is the source? Is it delimitted file?

Comment: it is a .xlsx file

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replicate this with column name with `\n` and got the error like `Column not found`

[image]

**Workaround**:  If you know the position of the column, you can use the `byPosition(<position>)` function.

[image]

**Output**

[image]